# Program checks if file exists before it is created

Tags: python, file, time

I have a problem with a code i'm writing. One of it's parts is responsible for creating a file, and it is also supposed to tell me if it was successful. If not, it should inform me as well, but the problem is - it checks if the file exists before it gets created. I tried to make a break between creation of file and checking if it exists by using time module (specifically time.sleep option, inserted in almost every place possible), but with no results. I also tried to use another way to check if the file exists. It didn't help. Whole thing works fine (excluding this part), because if the file is already there and i tell the program to create it, it tells me that it was successful, so it can read it properly, but it's too fast. I attached part of my code down below. Thank you in advance.

First way i tried, using os module:

```
path = 'D:\screen'

os.chdir(path)

exists = os.path.isfile('.\screenshot.png')
exists2 = os.path.isfile('.\screenshot2.png')
```

And here's the execution part:

```
def printer():
    pyautogui.screenshot('D:\SCREEN\screenshot.png')
    time.sleep(3)
    if exists:
        print("Screenshot was created successfully")
    else:
        print("Screenshot was not created successfully")

def printer2():
    pyautogui.screenshot('D:\SCREEN\screenshot2.png')
    time.sleep(3)
    if exists2:
        print ("Screenshot was created successfully")
    else:
        print ("Screenshot was not created successfully")
```

Second way i tried, using pathlib:

```
path = 'D:/screen'

file1 = Path("D:/screen/screenshot.png")
file2 = Path("D:/screen/screenshot2.png")
```

And the execution part:

```
def printer():
    pyautogui.screenshot('D:/SCREEN/screenshot.png')
    time.sleep(3)
    if file1.isfile():
        print("Screenshot was created successfully")
    else:
        print("Screenshot was not created successfully")


def printer2():
    pyautogui.screenshot('D:/SCREEN/screenshot2.png')
    time.sleep(3)
    if file2.isfile():
        print("Screenshot was created successfully")
    else:
        print("Screenshot was not created successfully")
```

Comment: Please show how and when you call `printer()` and `printer2()`. It is not clear that you even call these functions.

Comment: I use threads. Threads are called when the client recieves code from the server. ```t = threading.Thread(target = printer, name = 'thread1')
t2 = threading.Thread(target = printer2, name = 'thread2')  while True:
   data = s.recv(1024)
   print (data)
   if data[:1].decode("ISO-8859-1") == 'a':
       t.start()
   if data[:1].decode("ISO-8859-1") == 'b':
       t2.start() ```

Comment: You are using *nix path separators in all example code except at the top where you should be cautious and either escape \ with \\, or use `os.path.join`

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're expecting to happen, but if you're setting `exists` and `exists2` before the `screenshot()` function creates the file, those variables will tell you whether the file existed before `screenshot()`, and not afterwards which I think you want. Or have I misunderstood what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what pyautogui.screenshot() does but here goes:

Assuming that the first half of each attempt is executed before the printer functions are called, you are storing the result of os.path.isfile() before you've created the file you are testing.

You should also pick a case for the folder name, really it should be in a variable so that you are not typing it twice. You should also use os.path.join instead of typing directory separators.

In printer and printer2 of the first half you should be able to change exists/exists2 to a call to os.path.isfile().

In the simple case this should work:

```
def printer():
    pyautogui.screenshot('D:\screen\screenshot.png') #assume this attempts to create a file
    if os.path.isfile('.\screenshot.png'):
        print("Screenshot was created successfully")
    else:
        print("Screenshot was not created successfully")

path = 'D:\screen'
os.chdir(path)    
printer()
```

Answer (score 1):

Those variables (`file1`, `file2`) were assigned before creating the screenshot, hence they dont exist. `screenshot` actually returns a PIL image object. So you can check if without even using `os`.

```py
def printscreen():
    try:
        image = pyautogui.screenshot('D:/SCREEN/screenshot.png')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Exception occured during screenshotring {str(e)}')
```

If you want to still check with os if they exist, use it after the screenshot.

```py
pyautogui.screenshot('D:/SCREEN/screenshot.png')
assert os.file.exist('D:/SCREEN/screenshot.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

The best to check if the file exists or not is using a `try/catch` block.The problem in the code is that their is a race condition between the line `os.path.isfile('.\screenshot.png')` and the `if exists` part.

You can try to use the following -

```
  try:
      fh = open('.\screenshot.png', 'rw'):
      # Do something
  except FileNotFoundError:
      print("File not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of your answers. I was able to deal with my problem by using the solution proposed by Zonyl. It looks like the reason standing behind it was trivial(,,Those variables (file1, file2) were assigned before creating the screenshot" ,,Assuming that the first half of each attempt is executed before the printer functions are called, you are storing the result of os.path.isfile() before you've created the file you are testing.") but i'm thankful you helped me anyway. I hope another newbie in the future may find it useful.